# Singleton object context using Unity IoC in window forms whole application and database transactions problem

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, unity-container

I am using Unity IoC in C#, and DbContext with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager for application context with three layer architecture using entity framework, e.g.

This is a generic repository:

```
public interface IRepository<ModelClass, EntityClass>
    where ModelClass : class
    where EntityClass : class
{
    void Add(ModelClass entity);
    void Delete(ModelClass entity);
    void Update(ModelClass entity,int id);
    bool Save();
    void RefreshContext();
}
```

This is the Data Access layer interface:

```
public interface IShipmentAccess :
    IRepository<ShipmentOrder, ShipmentOrderEntity>
{
    List<ShipmentOrder> GetAllShipmentOrder();
    List<ShipmentOrder> GetShipmentOrderWithId(int id);
    bool UpdateFileExported(int id);
}
```

Implementation of DataAcess class

```
public class ShipmentOrderDataAccess : GenericRepository<ShipmentOrder,
    ShipmentOrderEntity>, IShipmentAccess
{
    ApplicationContext context;
    public ShipmentOrderDataAccess(ApplicationContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Implementation of Service class

```
public class ShipmentOrderService : BaseService
{
    ApplicationContext Context;

    IShipmentAccess shipmentAccess;
    PackingOrderService packingOrderService =
        DependencyInjection.DependencyInjection.Retrieve<PackingOrderService>();

    public ShipmentOrderService(ApplicationContext Context, IShipmentAccess
        shipmentAccess)
    {
        this.Context = Context;
        this.shipmentAccess = shipmentAccess;
    }
}
```

And our dependency injection class looks like as follows:

```
Container.RegisterType<DbContext, LogisticsERP.DA.Entities.ApplicationContext>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

Container.RegisterType<IShipmentAccess, ShipmentOrderDataAccess>();
```

But the problem here is that though we are using singleton life time manager (ContainerControlledLifetimeManager) of Unity and Entity Framework is is not loading updated data from database. I search on the Internet and found this solution to get updated data from database. Is it a correct solution?

```
public void RefreshContext()
{
    foreach (var entity in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        entity.Reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: You most likely misconfigured Unity by introducing a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). But unfortunately, there is no way for us to tell, as your code doesn't show the problem. Try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you are using your DbContext as singleton and if other apllications or instances of your application also do updates on your database then this is an expected result. This is a known issue of EntityFramework. When you get an entity, it caches it and when you later read the entity from your DbContext, it provides the same object from cache. It has nothing to do with unity. Your solution works but I recommend you to google about "EntityFramework caching"

Comment: Off-topic: why don't you inject `packingOrderService`?